# Rspec, `post` is not available on an example group: how to refactor

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I'm writing one of my first test.

I have a lot of test with this structure because I'm testing an api...

```
require 'rails_helper'

Rails.describe "Surveys", type: :request do

  let!(:survey) { create :survey, :id => 10 }
  let!(:user) { create :employee, :id => 51 }

  context "post wihout params" do
    params = 'Question_SKU=8&Language=Italian'
    post "/api/v1/surveys/complete_survey", params do
      header "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    end

    it "should respond 412" do
      expect(response).to have_http_status(412)
    end

    it "should not create associated record" do
      expect(survey.survey_results.count).to be 0  
    end
  end
end
```

For every test I must change the params and run the post...
With this syntax I have an error:

```
`post` is not available on an example group
```

I don't want to place the post inside each block, I have about 100 blocks...

Is there a way to avoid repetition?

Comment: move `post ....` into `it`

Comment: @OlegSobchuk I have to move it 100 times...

Comment: what about putting it into `before` block?

Answer (score 0):

You can put the `post` block inside a `before :each` block, like so:

```
before :each do
  params = 'Question_SKU=8&Language=Italian'
  post "/api/v1/surveys/complete_survey", params do
    header "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
  end
end
```

The block will be run before each example. If you want to run it only once, use `before :all`.